# Is the unit in Windows Forms printing always 100dpi point?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printdocument

What is the unit of the coordinate system used in *Windows Forms* printing using the [`PrintDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8) class? This information is needed in order to print something at a specific position and with a specific size.

In the [`PrintPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=netframework-4.8) event, the [`PrintPageEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds?view=netframework-4.8) instance has the properties [`Graphics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.graphics?view=netframework-4.8) and [`PageBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds?view=netframework-4.8). They seem to use the same coordinate system.

For an A4 portrait sheet, `PageBounds` returns a size of 827 by 1169. Given an A4 sheet is 210mm by 297mm, the unit `Graphics` / `PageBounds` unit seems to be pixels/points with 100dpi. (827 / 210 * 25.4 = 100.0278, 1169 / 297 * 25.4 = 99.9751).

Using 100dpi to scale and position the objects, the drawing result is correct. But is it always 100dpi? Or how can I query the unit?

(Querying `Graphics.DpiX` does not work. It returns 600dpi, which is the printer DPI but not the coordinate system DPI.)

```cs
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDocument_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle bounds = e.PageBounds; // For A4 portrait sheet: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 827 Height = 1169}
    float dpi = e.Graphics.DpiX; // 600
    DrawIt(e.Graphics);
}
```

Comment: I think you can set the [printerresolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The default value of the graphic `PageUnit` is [GraphicsUnit.Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphicsunit) for Printer. The scale (map) is calculated from the Printer current Dpi when the [Device Context is created](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PrinterSettings.cs,640), using the [PrinterUnitConvert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PrinterUnitConvert.cs,23)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the link to the source code. According to [PrinterUnitConvert.UnitsPerDisplay()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PrinterUnitConvert.cs,107), it's indeed always 100dpi. But it's probably safer to use the [PrinterUnitConvert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printerunitconvert?view=netframework-4.8) methods.

Comment: @TaW I don't want to change the printer resolution. 600dpi is okay. But I'd like to know what unit/dpi the associated *Graphics* instance uses.

Comment: The Graphics resolution is derived from the associated object, which can be a control (in that case it is the Monitor's dpi) or a Bitmap or in this case the page.

Comment: `PrinterUnitConvert` is used internally to map the current Printer Device Capabilities' Dpi settings to Display unit **for the Printer**. I.e., any Printer Dpi value is converted to a fixed value, for convenience. It was more *convenient* when the vast majority of Monitors used 96 Dpi, which is close enough to that value. Now, to implement a WYSIWYG interface, you need some more calculations, to map Screen Dpi to fixed Printer Dpi. Or print directly to the Printer without help from .Net. Which requires some more calculations... It depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi who pointed out that the unit is *Display*. The short answer is: It's always 100dpi for printing.

The *Graphics* instance uses [GraphicsUnit.Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphicsunit?view=netframework-4.8) as the [PageUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit?view=netframework-4.8). And for printers, this is *1/100 inch for printers*, i.e. 100dpi. The documentation says *"typically"* but this probably refers to the *video displays*.

It also coincides with [PrinterUnit.Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printerunit?view=netframework-4.8), which is always 0.01in.

As the *Graphics* measurements are also consistent with [`PageBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds?view=netframework-4.8), I can probably safely assume that `PageBounds` and other [`PrintPageEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds?view=netframework-4.8) properties also use *display units for printers* with 100dpi. It's not documented though.